# OpenLDAP - how to grant write access but without modify or delete? Is there any option?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have case like this - i want my PHP application to create accounts for employees in my OpenLDAP directory, so i have created dedicated account for this specific app and i'm going to use it only in this app. Next thing is to give this account permissions to write in *ou=people,dc=example,dc=com*, i have no problems with it - used *olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by dn="cn=app.name,ou=systems,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read* and all works OK. But now, i want this app to have only permission to create new users in this OU just to be sure developers of app won't mess something accidentally and delete all users from directory.

I'm looking for something like MySQL grants - e.g. user can INSERT into tables but can't DELETE, UPDATE or DROP. Is there any possibility? I've looked into OpenLDAP documentation and it says just about **write** or **manage** permissions :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html):

> To add or delete an entry, the subject must have write access to the entry's entry attribute AND must have write access to the entry's parent's children attribute.

From this, it seems like you could grant the PHP app's service account `write` permissions *only to the parent OU entry* **but not** on the user entries it creates. Since modification and deletion both require `write` permissions on the entry being modified or deleted, this should restrict the service account to your needs.

I am not sure exactly what the rule would look like, but try this:

```
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by dn="cn=app.name,ou=systems,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
```

Note that I replaced `dn.subtree` with `dn.base`.